# how to limit logging by calling method in spring logback

Tags: spring, call, logback, method-names

I'm poor at writing in English.
so sorry...

I want limit logging by method name base.
and use class & method wildcard.

I want...

**test.a.ClassA.java**

```
public class ClassA {
  public static void methodA() {
    logger.debug("methodA called.");

    test.b.ClassB.methodB();
  }
}
```

**test.b.ClassB.java**

```
public class ClassB {
  public static void methodB() {
    logger.debug("methodB called.");

    test.c.ClassC.methodC();
  }
}
```

**test.c.ClassC.java**

```
public class ClassC {
  public static void methodC() {
    logger.debug("methodC called.");
  }
}
```

**log-config.xml case 1**
- start log, ClassB all method.

```
<logger start="test.b.ClassB.*" level="debug">
  <appender-ref ref="debugAppender"/>
</logger>

-- log output --
methodB called.
methodC called.
-- methodA not logged.
```

**log-config.xml case 2**
- start log, ClassC all method.

```
<logger start="test.c.ClassC.*" level="debug">
  <appender-ref ref="debugAppender"/>
</logger>

-- log output --
methodC called.
-- methodA not logged.
-- methodB not logged.
```

**log-config.xml case 3**
- start log, ClassB specific method only.

```
<logger start="test.c.ClassB.methodB" level="debug"">
  <appender-ref ref="debugAppender"/>
</logger>

-- log output --
methodB called.
methodC called.
-- methodA not logged.
```

**log-config.xml case 4**
- ClassB specific method only. not calling class, method logging

```
<logger only="test.c.ClassB.methodB" level="debug"">
  <appender-ref ref="debugAppender"/>
</logger>

-- log output --
methodB called.
-- methodA not logged.
-- methodC not logged.
```

How to ??
custom logback ??
using LoggerFactory.getLogger ??

Help, please...